# express.js: show toastr message

Tags: node.js, express, pug, toastr

I'm trying to get Toastr library to work in my ExpressJS app! I scaffolded the app with the yeoman 'standard' Express Generator...

I've required the lib `express-toastr` and did the following:

in `app.js`:

```
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const session = require('express-session');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const toastr = require('express-toastr');

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session( {secret: 'xxx', saveUninitialized: true, resave: true} ));
app.use(flash());
app.use(toastr());
```

in `index.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const httpntlm = require('httpntlm');

router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {

    // parse inputs
    let user = req.body.user || "";
    let password = req.body.password || "";

    // save in session
    req.session.user = {user: user, password: password};

    // appropriate response to login attempt
    if (!req.session.user) {
        res.status(401).send();
    }
    else {
        req.toastr.success('Successfully logged in.', "You're in!");

        res.render('groups', {
            req: req
        });
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

In `index.jade`

```
#{req.toastr.render()}
```

I'm loading these files in my `<head>` section:

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.0.2/css/toastr.min.css')
script(src='/components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js')
script(src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.0.2/js/toastr.min.js')
```

Nothing is showing. What am I missing???

**-- UPDATE! --**

Here is my complete app.js file. I now try to use express-flash and making a dedicated route for showing a flash message. Still not working. Please help!

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const favicon = require('serve-favicon');
const logger = require('morgan');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const expressSanitizer = require('express-sanitizer');

const login = require('./routes/login');
const apply = require('./routes/apply');
const admin = require('./routes/admin');

var session = require('express-session');
var flash = require('express-flash');


var app = express();


// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));






app.use(session({
    cookie: { maxAge: 60000 },
    store: new session.MemoryStore,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: 'true',
    secret: 'secret'
}));
app.use(flash());

// Route that creates a flash message using the express-flash module
app.all('/express-flash', function( req, res ) {
    req.flash('success', 'This is a flash message using the express-flash module.');
    res.redirect(301, '/');
});







// sanitize inputs
app.use(expressSanitizer());

app.use('/', apply);
app.use('/apply', apply);
app.use('/login', login);
app.use('/admin', admin);


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using this middleware in your **app.js**, I found this [here](https://github.com/kamaln7/express-toastr)

```
app.use(function (req, res, next)
{
    res.locals.toasts = req.toastr.render()
    next()
});
```

and then access locals in your view as follows:

```
#{toasts}
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

So I am not familiar with your syntax in your index.jade file(!=). What does it do? If you change that line in your index to #{req.toastr.render()} it should work.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but still not working. Can you get it to work?
The syntax != is for escaping code. I misunderstood where to use it!
http://jade-lang.com/reference/code/